# python 2.6 bisect_right returning index instead of index to the right (index+1)

Tags: python, python-2.6

I am using bisect_right() to search in a txt file. 
Each line in the text file contains the following string "word1 word2 (tab) number" . That is, two words separeted by a blank (word1 and word2), a tab and a number.
I read the file as a list with readlines().
I am using the bisect_right with the parameter "word1 word2" (word1 (blank)word2) to find the index in the list where the (sub)string "word1 word2" is found. 
bisect_right seems to be finding the correct places and it returns the real index where the (sub) string is situated instead of the index to the right.
Shouldn't bisect_right return the index to the right if the (sub)string  (word1 (blank)word2) exists in the list? Could it be an issue when searching a substring?

Comment: If you are truly parsing text only, using `split()` and the [related string methods](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) might be a more robust method of dealing with things

Answer (score 1):

Searches using bisect module return an "insertion point", not an index.  An insertion point is the location *between* two values.  It is intended to be used like this `s.insert(i, 'new value')`.

Instead of insertion points, you want to search for the index of values in the sequence.  The examples in the docs to show how to do this:  http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html#searching-sorted-lists

Of course, all this only works if the list-of-strings is sorted before the binary search, but you probably already knew that :-)